# How to access pattern library (Photoshop CC)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, swatches

I have just defined a creation as a pattern but I cannot find where it has gone. I wish to use the pattern in Illustrator as a pattern swatch.

I appreciate this is a basic question but I have been trying to search for a while now and I am obviously missing something pretty simple. In Illustrator you get to it through the dropdown menu in the swatch tab but I cannot find the equivalent path. I have used sites such as adobe's help (https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/patterns-libraries-presets.html) and other online resources but none of them actually detail how to get the library up in the first place.

Comment: Which version of Photoshop you are using?

Comment: CC for both Photoshop and Illustrator